# Interfacing ATK-SIM 900A GSM/GPRS Module with Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, gsm, gprs

## Problem:

I have this ATK-SIM900A GSM / GPRS module which will be used to send sms. But I can't figure out how to interface it with an Arduino as there are no documentation available online.

## Module Specification

ATK-SIM900A GSM/GPRS Board from Alientek

[image: sim900a]

## Things I've tried so far

### Connection

I've tried connecting the module with Arduino in following manner

`SIM900A  TX <-> Arduino RX
SIM900A  RX <-> Arduino TX
SIM900A GND <-> Arduino GND`

I've powered up the ATK-SIM900A module with 12V-2A DC supply

### Programming

1. Tried SoftwareSerial library
2. Tried a some GSM libraries and programs

   - [GSM-GPRS-Shield](https://github.com/MarcoMartines/GSM-GPRS-GPS-Shield)
   - [Interfacing SIM900A with Arduino](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interfacing-SIM900A-GSM-Modem-with-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS)

What I'm doing wrong? Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

### Why it isn't a duplicate of other questions:

I am working with ATK-SIM900A GSM / GPRS module, it has different features and pinout than the module asked in those questions. I've tried the solution stated in this question ([Connecting GSM SIM900A module with Ardunio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138502/connecting-gsm-sim900a-module-with-ardunio)), it didn't work.

Comment: If it came without any documentation throw it away and buy a unit with documentation.

Comment: @LeonHeller, throwing away is not a solution, only this kind of module is available in my country. I hope someone has used it and has a workable solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What exactly did you try from the other question?

Comment: @hcabral Tried to connect the module through RS-232 Serial port.

Comment: @Manash Did you use the level converters the answers to that question were talking about?

Comment: It has a built in RS-232 to TTL logic converter. I just directly connected it. One more thing, the module as two pairs of RX-TX. One pair is beside the RS-232 and another pair is on the regular board pinout. Tried both of them, didn't work. @hcabral

Comment: @Manash Do you mean the GSM board has a built-in RS232 - TTL converter?  Are you sure of that?  I can see an MAX3232 chip on your board which suggests to me that the board expects an RS232 signal as input.  If you are really sure of that I guess I don't know how to help you.  I'd try using an oscilloscope to see if the board is sending any information on its TX pin and comparing it with what you Arduino is receiving.

Comment: The pinouts on the RS-232 side says TTL-RX, TTL-TX, so I'm pretty sure that it has a built in logic converter. I don't have any oscilloscope right now so can't check that.

Comment: What is it that do not work? "It did't work" is not that specific. Generally it does not matter what kind of breakout board do you have, if the power and logic levels are ok, then the sim900 should answer the at commands. UART of the arduino is working correctly?

Comment: Sim900A is not responding to AT commands and yes UART of the arduino is working correctly.

Comment: Status LED is on?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Solved the problem @BenceKaulics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I am just posting the solution if anyone needs it. Everyone seems to downvote the problem instead of giving solutions.

- First of all, remove all the jumpers [see the picture]

[image: rem]

- Then add two Male to Female cable to the S-TX and S-RX [Here S stands for SIM900, you can find the pins after removing the jumpers.]
- Short the grounds of both arduino and ATK-SIM900A module
- S-TX must be connected to the arduino RX and S-RX must be connected to the arduino TX.
- Normally power up the module [Don't forget to press `PWR Key` afterwards]

## Code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define BAUD 9600
#define RX 10
#define TX 11

SoftwareSerial gsm(RX, TX);

int8_t sendATcommand(char* ATcommand, char* expected_answer, unsigned int timeout) {

  uint8_t x = 0,  answer = 0;
  char response[100];
  unsigned long previous;

  memset(response, '\0', 100);    // Initialize the string

  delay(100);

  while ( gsm.available() > 0) gsm.read();   // Clean the input buffer

  gsm.println(ATcommand);    // Send the AT command


  x = 0;
  previous = millis();

  // this loop waits for the answer
  do {
    // if there are data in the UART input buffer, reads it and checks for the asnwer
    if (gsm.available() != 0) {
      response[x] = gsm.read();
      x++;
      Serial.println(response);
      // check if the desired answer is in the response of the module
      if (strstr(response, expected_answer) != NULL)
      {
        answer = 1;
      }
    }
    // Waits for the asnwer with time out
  } while ((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) < timeout));

  return answer;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(BAUD);
  gsm.begin(BAUD);
}


//Code for sending sms, replace the stars and country code with your corresponding phone number

void loop() 
{
  sendATcommand("AT+CMGF=1\r\n", "OK", 500);
  sendATcommand("AT+CMGS=\"+880******582\"\r", "OK", 500);
  delay(500);
  gsm.println("Hello world"); //The message to be sent
  delay(500);
  gsm.println((char)26); // Done
  delay(500);
}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: At first you wrote to connect SRX to ATX and STX to ARX. But in your code you defined 10 as RX and 11 as TX! Is there any purpose for it?